# WCF error 'There was an error while trying to serialize parameter...'

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization

My service works for other methods but when I try to invoke a method with a more complicated collection I get the error (from Service Trace Viewer)

'There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetDataEventSetResult. The InnerException message was 'Type 'MimosaServerLib.DAInt' with data contract name 'DAInt:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MimosaServerLib' is not expected...'

Answers to questions with the same error that I've seen involve changing the class definition to turn off 'ProxyCreationEnabled' but the classes I'm working with (`DataEventSet`, `DAInt`) come from a file that's been auto generated using xsd tool that I've been given. i.e. I ought not to be changing it.

I create the `DataEventSet` object, which is exposed, like so:

```
    private DataEventSet CreateDataEventSet()
    {
        DataEventSet aDataEventSet = new DataEventSet();
        DataEvent[] dataEvents = new DataEvent[2];
        DAInt aDAInt = new DAInt();
            aDAInt.id = 100100100;
            aDAInt.value = 1;
            dataEvents[0] = aDAInt;
        DADataSeq aDADataSeq = new DADataSeq();
            aDADataSeq.id = 200100100;
            double[] vals = new double[2];
                vals[0] = 5;
                vals[1] = 44;
            aDADataSeq.values = vals;
            double[] vals2 = new double[2];
                vals2[0] = 1;
                vals2[1] = 1;
            aDADataSeq.xAxisDeltas = vals2;
            aDADataSeq.xAxisStart = 0;
            dataEvents[1] = aDADataSeq;
        aDataEventSet.id = 0;
        Site aSite = new Site();
            aSite.category = SITE_CATEGORY.SITE_SPECIFIC;
        aDataEventSet.site = aSite;
        OsacbmTime aTime = new OsacbmTime();
            aTime.tick_time = 12313246;
            aTime.time = "2007-09-20T14:46:04.123";
            aTime.time_type = OsacbmTimeType.OSACBM_TIME_MIMOSA;
        aDataEventSet.time = aTime;
        aDataEventSet.dataEvents = dataEvents;

        return aDataEventSet;
    }
```

Edit: The class definition of the `DataEventSet`

```
//This source code was auto-generated by xsd

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mimosa.org/OSACBMV3-1l")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mimosa.org/OSACBMV3-1l", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class DataEventSet {

private bool alertStatusField;

private bool alertStatusFieldSpecified;

private DataEvent[] dataEventsField;

private ulong idField;

private Site siteField;

private OsacbmTime timeField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public bool alertStatus {
    get {
        return this.alertStatusField;
    }
    set {
        this.alertStatusField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool alertStatusSpecified {
    get {
        return this.alertStatusFieldSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.alertStatusFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("dataEvents", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public DataEvent[] dataEvents {
    get {
        return this.dataEventsField;
    }
    set {
        this.dataEventsField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public ulong id {
    get {
        return this.idField;
    }
    set {
        this.idField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public Site site {
    get {
        return this.siteField;
    }
    set {
        this.siteField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public OsacbmTime time {
    get {
        return this.timeField;
    }
    set {
        this.timeField = value;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you will need to add the `KnownType(typeof(DAInt))` attribute to the `DataEventSet` class because you are using it in a polymorphic manner. I usually add my changes to the generated code in a new file called something like DataEventSet.xsd.nongenerated.cs. This is why the generated code creates the classes as partial classes.

Inside DataEventSet.xsd.nongenerated.cs, you'll have something like this:

```
[KnownType(typeof(DAInt))]
public partial class DataEventSet {
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you can always try changing the contract to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of the `DataContractSerializer`. That should work well because it uses the Xml attributes created by xsd.exe.

You can specify that the runtime uses the XmlSerializer by adding the [XmlSerializerFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute to the service contract.

Comment: Thanks! It works in the WCF Test Client now. But when I try to access the service with an external Client I get a 'NetDispatcherFaultException': "http://tempuri.org/:GetDataEventSetResult. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 898. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MimosaServerLib:DataEvent' contains data from a type that maps to the name."

Comment: Was that using the KnownType() attribute?

Comment: Yes, I also had to add [KnownType(typeof(DADataSeq))]